# Distinguish Entry in FormData - File or string

Tags: typescript, form-data

I am accessing a `FormData` ([LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)) value which is of

```
type FormDataEntryValue = File | string;
```

.

What is a safe method to determine whether the value is a `File` or `string`?

Answer should obviously not include `as`, `any`, ..

Comment: Can you check with `typeof value === 'string'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

```js
const val: FormDataEntryValue = ...
if (typeof val === 'string') {
  // type is inferred to be a string
} else {
  // type is inferred to be a File
}
```

Comment: I completely erased "typeof" from my brain... thanks bro ;D